# Adding custom header in laravel reponse not working

Tags: laravel, api, response-headers

I need to add a custom headers in laravel api response.
So, I've created a middleware with this handle() method.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, int $cacheTimeInMinutes = null)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        return $response->withHeaders([
            config('constant.cacheable_header_name') => '1',
            'Cache-Control' => 'public, s-maxage='. 60 * ($cacheTimeInMinutes ?? config('constant.cache_time_in_minutes')),
        ]);
    }
```

I've registered the middleware in kernel.php inside routeMiddleware array.
and used in route like

```
Route::get('list', [ListController::class, 'list'])->middleware('cacheable:1');
```

It does added the custom headers when doing `dd(response)` inside middleware handle method. but on returning response, it shows the default headers only.

What am I missing?